# Dealing with null values in Laravel database query?

Tags: php, mysql, null, laravel, laravel-4

I am finding that I often need to select a field, based on a condition other than the id.

So, `$user = User::where('last_login', $lastLogin)->where('last_warning', $lastWarning)->get();` works perfectly.

That is until you set one of the where's to allow nulls (let's do `last_login`).

That is, it can either have a value or be null.

That means you need to use one of two function `where()` or `whereNull()` and to do that you need to break the chain, so it becomes

```
$user = User::where('last_warning', $lastWarning);

is_null($lastLogin) ? $user->whereNull('last_login') : $user->where('last_login', $lastLogin);

$user = $user->get();
```

I am wondering if `where` has a way to deal with this? as currently if you pass `null` through to where you get `where column = null` which doesn't work!

Answer (score 5):

Two options:

**Option 1:**

```
if (is_null($lastLogin))
{
    $user = User::whereNull('last_login')->where('last_warning', $lastWarning)->get();
}
else
{
    $user = User::where('last_login', $lastLogin)->where('last_warning', $lastWarning)->get();
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
$user = User::where('last_login', (is_null($lastLogin) ? 'IS' : '=') ,$lastLogin)->where('last_warning', $lastWarning)->get();
```

Option two makes the query '`where last_login = x'` or '`where last_login IS null`'

Comment: Is there ant reason that Where() doesn't have any logic to do that automatically if null is passed?

Comment: Sorry - you'd have to as Taylor that. Post it as an issue/request on github perhaps...

Comment: Yeah, might fork, create the patch, and then submit the request with a pull request.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
User::where(function($query) use ($lastlogin)
        {
            if(is_null($lastLogin))
            {
                $query->whereNull('last_login');
            }
            else
            {
                $query->where('last_login', '=', $lastLogin);
            }
        })->get();
```

It is a good solution when dealing with long queries with more than one parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DB::raw() as well:

```
User::where('last_login', 'IS', DB::raw('null'))->where_last_warning($lastWarning)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Laravel 5.3 you are now able to `->where('column', null)` to automatically produce `WHERE column IS NULL`.

If using variable, make sure that they have PHP `null` strict value.